# Equals is not implemented

Tags: c#

I have the following class in C# 10:

```
public sealed record Country : IEquatable<Country>
{
    public string Language { get; set; } = "xx";

    public bool Equals(Country? other)
    {
        if (other is null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Language == other.Language;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => Language.GetHashCode();
}
```

Which when compiling will bring the following compile time error:

> Interface member 'bool System.IEquatable<Country?>.Equals(Country?)' is not implemented

Which is... a very weird error message for the type in question. I tried varying the nullability of the `Country` parameter, and I tried generating the "missing" method, which will generate the following method for my IDE:

```
public bool Equals(Country? other) => throw new NotImplementedException();
```

And then, of course, the error switches to

> Member with the same signature is already declared

Generating the `Equals()` method directly will just override the existing method.

What is going on here? Not all of my colleagues have the same error message for this class, so it might just be something that has nothing to do with the class. (I think I'm the only one on Windows, for example.) `dotnet build` works, so it might just be a problem with Rider 2021.3.2, but that's the IDE my colleagues use as well.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgYgDsBXAG1IENhSYACGQqmgWACgABAJgEY232AzLQDOMCjQy1YkKJIDCEYoQAuUAJ60QtAJIBRAI7EKypjAA8CparUA+NgG82tZ7UGvuABloAZCoQDmRv509rTBygDcIjCRtAC+tAC8tABECAgpEXysLq5CwBAQpLQGRqTCABSWKuoA/LQQygAWMFAAlE4ujjm5LgCWAGa0FY0tULR9wrQk5B09vbTdCwvsAOy0A+KiWfO9cdnLruu+AUF0icmjrQB0J4EUwTu5+6ydzm4QAG6tUH0YdH0VLQAOIxAASFGETQU/wqbSSNh8fnuwWuoOUEKhMJgcJ2cSAA==)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its related to your record usage, records already implement this interface and IEquatable is not needed

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records#equality-members

Quick test in Visual studio and its likely IDE issue.

Answer (score 2):

Records implement equality automatically: that's one of the main advantages of using one.

We can see this in [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io). If we paste in:

```
public sealed record Country
{
    public string Language { get; set; } = "xx";
}
```

and select "Results: C#", we can see that the generated code includes:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return EqualityComparer<Type>.Default.GetHashCode(EqualityContract) * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(<Language>k__BackingField);
}

[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(2)]
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return Equals(obj as Country);
}

[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(2)]
public bool Equals(Country other)
{
    return (object)this == other || ((object)other != null && EqualityContract == other.EqualityContract && EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(<Language>k__BackingField, other.<Language>k__BackingField));
}
```

as well as definitions of the `==` and `!=` operators.

[See here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgYgDsBXAG1IENhSYACGQqmgWACgABAJgEY232AzLQDOMCjQy1YkKJIDCEYoQAuUAJ5sA3m1q7ag/dwAMtADIVCAc2IVLdTbTvKA3CJgvaAX1oBeWgCIEBH9nNk8gA==).

If you do want to override equality in a record, then you do that as you have done, by specifying your own `bool Equals(Counter? other)` and `int GetHashCode()` methods. There's no need to specify that the record implements `IEquatable<Country>` however, because the compiler will automatically add this interface for records.

Note that it's good practice to put in a test for `EqualityContract == other.EqualityContract`. This is used to make sure that you're not comparing a record of type `Country` with one which is a subclass of `Country`:

```
public bool Equals(Country? other)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        return true;
    if (other is null || EqualityContract != other.EqualityContract)
        return false;
        
    return Language == other.Language;
}

public override int GetHashCode() => Language.GetHashCode();
```

[See on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgYgDsBXAG1IENhSYACGQqmgWACgABAJgEY232AzLQDOMCjQy1YkKJIDCEYoQAuUAJ60QtAJIBRAI7EKypjAA8CparUA+NgG82tZ7UGvuABloAZCoQDmRv509rTBygDcIjCRtAC+tAC8tABECAgpEU4u2c5uwBAQpLQGRqTCABSWKuoA/LQQygAWMFAAlLm0jqwuvbQAlgBmtBUASjCDrQxgMKXilc39wmgNza1tHT192+wA7LSqxDBZW9tDI40tUAPCtCTktLi4JYbi/cpqCjUUYMq0AITJS6tAB0c1I70+EG+v022x2+0G82OnXhtFRLj2Pj8gQowSSQLWUBBvgCQRRp3inU6bggADdWlB+hg6P0VLQAOIxAASFGETQULIqbSSNmxZLxMBBXOUvP5gpgwpOcSAA===).